# Evaluation of the first three terms of $e^x $ in terms of the Hermite polynomials

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, hermite-polynomials

> **Q:** Evaluate of the first three terms of $e^x $ in terms of the Hermite
>   polynomials.

The coefficients $a_n $ are given by $$a_n = \frac {1}{2^n n! \sqrt {\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}e^x H_n (x) dx$$

So for $a_0$, we have to solve the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}e^x H_0 (x) dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{x-x^2} dx$

Can someone tell me how I can evaluate this integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{x-x^2} dx$? Or perhaps suggest a different way to calculate the terms?

Comment: Complete the square: $x - x^2 = \frac{1}{4} - (x - \frac{1}{2})^2$. Then $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{x - x^2}\, dx = e^{1/4}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x - 1/2)^2}\, dx = e^{1/4}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\, dx.$$ Can you evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\, dx$?

Comment: The Rodrigues' formula for the Hermite polynomials might be useful here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues'_formula. (Warning: I'm not sure if that's the physicist H_n or the probabalist H_n.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{x-x^2} dx=e^{\frac{1}{4}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x\sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2} dx$

$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}e^{\frac{1}{4}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(u)^2} du$

$=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\sqrt{2}}e^{\frac{1}{4}}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(u)^2} du)$

We know that $P(X\in{\mathbb{R}})=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(u)^2} du)=1$ where X is centered and normally distributed

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{x-x^2} dx=\sqrt{\pi}e^{\frac{1}{4}}$

Answer (score 2):

Just note that

$$
x-x^2 = -(x^2 -x + 1/4) + 1/4 = -(x-1/2)^2 + 1/4
$$

And then call $t = x - 1/2$, so that

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\rm d}x\;e^{x - x^2} = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\rm d}x\;e^{-(x - 1/2)^2}e^{1/4} = e^{1/4} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{\rm d}t\;e^{-t^2} = e^{1/4}\sqrt{\pi}
$$

Comment: I think you should remove the $\sqrt(2)$ in your final result