# Why is $e^x$ having a different series expansion in terms of the Hermite polynomials?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, hermite-polynomials

I had asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2046623/evaluation-of-the-first-three-terms-of-ex-in-terms-of-the-hermite-polynomial) yesterday relating to "*Evaluation of the first three terms of $e^x$ in terms of the Hermite polynomials*".

Yes, my problem for that question was solved and I was successfully able to evaluate the integrals.

But what struck me was that the final expression was:

$$f(x)=e^{\frac{1}{4}}\left[\frac{1}{8}H_2(x)+\frac{1}{2}H_1(x)+H_0(x)\right]+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}H_1(x)$$

which is not the same as the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ if we replace $H_n(x)$ by the tabulated values. But the working out and the formulae are correct as evident in the the hyperlinked question.

Is what I have done correct. But then why do we have that $e^{\frac{1}{4}}$ in wfront?

Someone please help.

Comment: Where did the last term come from? You found that $\langle f | H_n \rangle=e^{1/4}\{1,1/2, 1/8,1/48,\cdots\}$ so that $f(x)= e^{1/4}(H_0(x) + H_1(x)/2 + H_2(x)/8 + \cdots)$

Comment: @caverac The last term came from evaluating $a_1$. I split $H_1$ as $(2x-1)$ and $1$ and the $2$ integrals gave me the $2$ values.

Comment: Just to make sure we are talking about the same thing, you call (?) $$a_n = \frac{1}{\pi^{1/2}2^n n!}\int dx\; f(x)H_n(x)e^{-x^2}$$  If this is the case, then $$ a_1 = \frac{1}{\pi^{1/2}}\int dx\; e^x(2x - 1)e^{-x^2} + \frac{1}{\pi^{1/2}}\int dx\; e^x(1)e^{-x^2} = 0 + \frac{1}{2}e^{1/4} = \frac{1}{2}e^{1/4}$$

Comment: @caverac Yes, it is. But the first integral in $a_1$ comes out as $\int_0^\infty e^{-z} dz = 0 + 1 =1$ where $z=x^2-x$. Isn't it so?

Comment: No, it is 0, because the integral is over the whole real line and the function you're integrating is odd about $x=1/2$, so the integral vanishes

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx\; e^x(2x-1)e^{-x^2} = 0
$$

Comment: Why would it be the same as the Taylor expansion? (If I understand you right you found the first four terms of the Hermite expansion.  There is no reason the corresponding polynomial should be the same as the Taylor polynomila of degree 4)

Comment: @caverac Thanks for the correction. But then what should be the conclusion? Is the series different from $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}$ ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two expansions need not to be the same. You can imagine that the function $f(x)$ is a vector, if $u_n(x)$ is a basis then

$$
f(x) = \sum_n \langle u | f\rangle u_n(x) = \sum_n a_n u_n(x)
$$

where $\langle \cdot | \cdot\rangle$ denotes the inner product. Depending on the selection of the basis $u_n(x)$, the coefficients of the expansion $a_n$ are going to be different, and so is going to be the value of the RHS sum, should it be truncated at a given number $n$

Answer (score 3):

I will use the statistician's Hermite polynomials, the answer is still the same.

The coefficients in both a Taylor expansion
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n 
$$
and the Hermite expansion
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty d_n H_n(x)
$$
are both related to the $n^\textrm{th}$ derivative of the function.  It is well
known that for the Taylor expansion, the coefficients are proportional to the $n^\textrm{th}$ derivative evaluated at the expansion point (let's take zero)
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{n!} \frac{\partial^nf(0)}{\partial x^n} 
$$
whereas the coefficient in the Hermite expansion is the weighted integral of the
$n^\textrm{th}$ derivative over the entire real line
$$
d_n = \frac{1}{n!} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\partial^nf(x)}{\partial x^n}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\frac{dx}{\sqrt{2\pi}} 
$$
For $e^x$ all the derivatives are $e^x$ and the integral over the real line is $e^{\frac{1}{2}}$.  Therefore the Hermite expansion is
$$
e^x = e^{\frac{1}{2}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{H_n(x)}{n!}
$$
To see how this can be related back to the Taylor expansion, we instead calculate the Hermite expansion of $e^{x\sqrt{t}}$ and find
$$
e^{x\sqrt{t}} = e^{\frac{1}{2}t}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{t}^nH_n(x)}{n!}
$$
Making the substitution $y=x\sqrt{t}$ leads to
$$
e^{y} = e^{\frac{1}{2}t}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{t}^nH_n\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{t}}\right)}{n!}
$$
The quantity $\sqrt{t}^nH_n\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{t}}\right)$ is known as the Hermite martingale, but note it is still monic, ie the coefficient of the highest order power ($n$) is $1$, all other powers are multiplied by a power of $t$.

Taking the $t\rightarrow 0$ limit of the RHS leads to the Taylor series, since
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \sqrt{t}^nH_n\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{t}}\right) = y^n.
$$